# how to install the latest Elixir version (1.2 at this date) on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, elixir, ubuntu-15.10

I wan to install the latest Elixir version on Ubuntu 15.10. I have follow the [install](http://elixir-lang.org/install.html#unix-and-unix-like). But I only got `Elixir 1.1.0-dev`. But the latest version is 1.2. How do I get it?

Comment: Did you have another version of Elixir installed prior to attempting to install this version?  If so, make sure you get rid of the old version first.

Comment: You can use download Elixir packages from Erlang Solutions. For Ubuntu there are packages including `Elixir 1.2.3` https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case you'll need to build from source:

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir

From the website:

> To run Elixir from source, clone this repository to your machine,
>   compile and test it:
>
> git clone https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir.git
>
> cd elixir
>
> make clean test

Comment: I have this error on `make clean test` : ```cd lib/elixir && "/home/tom/Downloads/elixir/rebar" clean
/usr/bin/env: escript: No such file or directory
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 127
```

Comment: Are you running the command under sudo?  If not, I'd try that and see what you get.

Comment: What happens if you just do `make test` (leave out `clean`)?

Comment: ```/bin/sh: 1: erl: not found
At least Erlang 18.0 is required to build Elixir
Makefile:61: recipe for target 'lib/elixir/src/elixir.app.src' failed
make: *** [lib/elixir/src/elixir.app.src] Error 1
```

Comment: This is what I get for assuming things.  You have to have Erlang installed before you attempt to install Elixir. You can get Erlang via the method that @CodyPoll outlined in his answer.

Comment: Given the state of the machine, it may be better to follow your method and simply compile erlang. It's not a difficult process, though compilation can take a while depending on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

From [the Elixir site](http://elixir-lang.org/install.html#unix-and-unix-like):

- `wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb` - Add Erlang solutions repo
- `sudo apt-get update` - Get packages from repo listed in apt
- `sudo apt-get install esl-erlang` - Install the Erlang/OTP platform and all of its applications
- `sudo apt-get install elixir` - Install Elixir

Even though it says 1.0 in the `dpkg` command, it will also make the latest version available to you.

Comment: it's the Elixir 1.1.0-dev not elixir 1.2

Comment: Hm... I'll have to go check our build process to see what the steps we use are, because 1.2 is available in our environment. I was fairly certain this is what we were doing, but it probably changed since I last checked.

Comment: I just did this on a fresh VM, and it installed 1.2. I can also confirm that my company uses this process in production, and we are using 1.2. Make sure you don't already have elixir installed on the machine, and that there are no conflicting external repos in your configuration.

Comment: So i have elixir 1.1.0-dev I uninstall it with `sudo apt-get autoremove elixir` and now when I do all those command but crash on `install esl-erlang`

Comment: ```Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 esl-erlang : Depends: libssl0.9.8 but it is not installable
              Recommends: erlang-mode but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Is there a way you can get the machine to a fresh state? If it's a server, would the ops team be willing to reprovision? If a VM, can you rebuild it? If it's you're native dev machine... Ouch. Unfortunately, my knowledge of Ubuntu system administration is extremely limited.

Comment: I had the same issue. You don't have to install from source you need to install something like libssl-dev but I can't find it now: e.g: sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

Comment: It was an my ubuntu desktop. I try again with a fresh ubuntu 15.10 I a got the same issue